# th doesn't support align attribute

Tags: html

in HTML tables when I write `<td align="right">` it works. But when I write `<th align="right">`, it doesn't work. 
Why is that. Generally `th` (table head) is same as `td` but the text is emphasized.

Comment: its working [check](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFS4EZAYGJOC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding the `align` attribute into your mark-up (a presentational attribute and deprecated in HTML5), you are better off using the CSS declaration:

```
text-align: right;
```

**Working Example:**

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

th, td {
width: 180px;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>Fruit</th>
<th>Veg</th>
<th>Nuts</th>
</thead>

<tr>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>Carrot</td>
<td>Hazelnut</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pear</td>
<td>Swede</td>
<td>Almond</td>
</tr>
</table>
```